# How to detect/deal with spies/trolls?

Tags: ingress

Some agents like to play spies, but still play within the rules (they do not [create multiple accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/187884/48822)). **How do we detect who is a spy and avoid infiltration, and how to deal with it?**

Applies to real-life [anomalies](https://www.ingress.com/events) as well as in the scanner, where an agent (read troll) of the same faction may act against the faction.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to use is a tactic called the Barium meal test or "Canary Trap". Give all the potential spies slightly different information regarding specific high value portals you're going to hit. Have individuals hit those portals, and when it's defended immediately, you'll have your spy.

Answer (score 1):

**[Real-life]**

Check the agent's phone that they are in your faction before dropping anything